# If sheet name already exists, put a message in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a code that names a sheet after the value in a cell. I am extremely new to code.

If a sheet name already exists, I want to put a message in a cell next to it - `cell.setValue.("Sheet name already exists.")`
If it doesn't exists `cell.setValue.("")` and change sheet name.

How can I do this?

I have tried many different if statements and none of them worked. I get an error message after running them saying sheet name already exists. The base of my code is below.

```
function onEdit() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var oldsheetname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();

  var newsheetname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,2);


   if (oldsheetname !== newsheetname && newsheetname !== "")
  {SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().setName(newsheetname) && cell.setValue("") };}
```

If a sheet name already exists, I want to put a message in a cell next to it - `cell.setValue.("Sheet name already exists.")` If it doesn't exists `cell.setValue.("")` and change sheet name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check if `.getSheetByName(oldname)` returns true or not and use `.setValue()` accordingly:

```gas
if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(oldname)){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 2).setValue("Sheet name already exists");
}
else {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 2).clear();
}
```